# Polynomial fitting with R using poly vs. I function

Tags: r, linear-regression, linearmodels

I'm trying to understanding polynomial fitting with R. From my research on the internet, there apparently seems to be two methods. Assuming I want to fit a cubic curve `ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d` into some dataset, I can either use:

```
lm(dataset, formula = y ~ poly(x, 3))
```

or

```
lm(dataset, formula = y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3))
```

However, as I try them in R, I ended up with two different curves with complete different intercepts and coefficients. Is there anything about polynomial I'm not getting right here?

Comment: Different coefficients... probably. Almost certainly in fact.  But different predicts? Unlikely. You need to show full code if you expect a careful consideration of your claim.

Comment: The predictions are almost certainly the same. If you want poly to mimic using I then use the raw=TRUE parameter.

Answer (score 2):

This comes down to what the different functions do. `poly` generates orthonormal polynomials. Compare the values of `poly(dataset$x, 3)` to `I(dataset$x^3)`. Your coefficients will be different because the values being passed directly into the linear model (as opposed to indirectly, through either the `I` or `poly` function) are different.

As 42 pointed out, your predicted values will be fairly similar. If `a` is your first linear model and `b` is your second, `b$fitted.values - a$fitted.value` should be fairly close to 0 at all points.

Answer (score 0):

I got it now. There seems to be a difference between R computation of raw polynomial vs orthogonal polynomial. Thanks, everyone for the help.